# how to get height of an entity in ursina?

Tags: python-3.x, game-development, ursina

I'm making a Brick Breaker Game using Ursina in python. I've created some entities which work as ball and bar.

```py
bar = Entity(model='quad', color=color.blue, position=(4.5, -10, 0), scale=(3, 0.3), collider='box')

ball = Entity(model='sphere', color=color.red, position=(4.5, -9.5, 0), scale=0.25, collider='sphere')
```

I want the ball at the upper center of the bar without manually setting the x and y value. Like this:

[image: my_imagination]

For this I want the width and height of the bar. How can I get that? I tried `bar.width`. But it returns 'Entity' object has no attribute 'width'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can use `bar.scale_x` and `bar.scale_y`.

For more options you can check https://www.ursinaengine.org/api_reference and see Entity (https://www.ursinaengine.org/api_reference#Entity)